# How to replicate native List styling with VStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need deeper customization that the `List` cannot provide so I'm having to rebuild it using using a `ScrollView`, `VStack`, and `ForEach` views. I would like to replicate the native look of the `List` though but it is proving to be much more challenging.

This is what I have:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let data: [String] = (0..<5).map { "Row \($0)" }

    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            List(data) { element in
                NavigationLink(element) {
                    Text(element)
                }
            }
            .previewDisplayName("List")
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(data) { element in
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text(element)
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text(element)
                                Spacer()
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    .font(.caption)
                            }
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                        .padding(.vertical, 8)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        if element != data.last {
                            Divider()
                                .padding(.leading)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(20)
                .padding(.vertical)
            }
            .previewDisplayName("ForEach")
        }
        .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 350, height: 350))
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}
```

It took a lot of code to get this done and it's still off:

[image]

Is there a better way to inherit the native styling of `List`? I tried applying `.listStyle` on the `VStack` but this didn't work.

Comment: IMO wild goose chase - in every OS version List looks (and even behaves) differently... many things private, so...

Comment: I agree, but the `List` assumes that it is the root view and doesn't expose everything. I'm trying to build something like the App Store where there are horizontal carousels and other custom views dispersed within. Good point about displaying on multiple platforms.

Comment: Maybe I can achieve what I need if I can apply different styling to different `Section` views within the `List`. Is it possible for example to have one `Section` styled as an inset group and another `Section` as plain and to the edges? Also removing the extra padding at the top of the `List` seems to be a challenge too.